# Cannot deploy with Capistrano 3.2.1 to remote server. Errors authenticating git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, bitbucket, capistrano3, chef-solo

I'm getting an SSH authentication error when deploying a Ruby on Rails 4.0.4 app with Capistrano 3.2.1 to my digital ocean app, web, and db servers. SSH keys have been added to bitbucket.

Current stack:
* Chef 11
* Berkshelf 2.0.13
* Rails 4.0.4
* Ruby 2.1.0
* Capistrano 3.2.1
* repo on Bitbucket.org
* DigitalOcean app/web server and db server

I get the following error when deploying with Capistrano using `cap production deploy`:

```
...
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.748529 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790018 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: read 84 bytes
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790228 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: received packet nr 18 type 95 len 60
I, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790319 #8204]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[3fdc6dc8e5a4]: channel_extended_data: 0 1 32b
DEBUG [1547c1bb]    conq: repository access denied.
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790608 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: read 180 bytes
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790723 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: received packet nr 19 type 95 len 156
I, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790776 #8204]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[3fdc6dc8e5a4]: channel_extended_data: 0 1 126b
DEBUG [1547c1bb]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [1547c1bb]    
DEBUG [1547c1bb]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [1547c1bb]    and the repository exists.
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.790959 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: read 36 bytes
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791018 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: received packet nr 20 type 96 len 12
I, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791076 #8204]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[3fdc6dc8e5a4]: channel_eof: 0
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791320 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: read 104 bytes
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791411 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: received packet nr 21 type 98 len 44
I, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791467 #8204]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[3fdc6dc8e5a4]: channel_request: 0 exit-status false
DEBUG [1547c1bb] Finished in 3.136 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791624 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: received packet nr 22 type 97 len 12
I, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791664 #8204]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[3fdc6dc8e5a4]: channel_close: 0
D, [2014-05-13T11:10:20.791742 #8204] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3fdc6de01224]: queueing packet nr 18 type 97 len 28
```

SSH keys set up to connect both local and remote repos (tested with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`). Here's the output of `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` on remote server:

```
root@appserver:~# ssh -v git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:gabethegrape
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:gabethegrape
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.167]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
logged in as gabethegrape.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
Transferred: sent 3632, received 2904 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 126916.9, received 101477.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

#### (remote)./ssh/config

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

#### (local) chef-repo/config/deploy/deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'repo'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git'
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :branch, "master"
set :user, "root"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache


# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
set :format, :pretty

set :stages, ["dev", "staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "production"
set :deploy_to, '/home/apps'
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  # keys: [File.join(ENV["HOME"], ".ssh", "id_rsa")],
  verbose: :debug,
  user: fetch(:user)
}

role :web, "digital_ocean_appserver"
role :app, "digital_ocean_appserver"
role :db, "digital_ocean_dbserver", :primary => true

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

#### (local) chef-repo/config/deploy/production.rb

```
server 'digital_ocean_appserver', user: 'root', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
server 'digital_ocean_dbserver', user: 'root', roles: %w{db}, my_property: :my_value
set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["production"] || "master"
set :deploy_to, '/home/apps'
```

Any ideas why I can't authenticate and connect to bitbucket on deploy?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: does your remote key has permissions in bitbucket?

Comment: from your output, I would say that is problem, you would need to add keys in your bitbucket repo.

Comment: @juanpastas I have the keys in the repo for both my local and remote machines. When I enter `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` it outputs `logged in as gabethegrape`. `You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had a similar problem with GitHub's private repos

We fixed with this:

```
#config/deploy.rb
set :repo_url, 'https://user:password@github.com/user/repo.git'
```

This sets the user & password explicitly each time, which allows us to deploy the code without the error you're receiving

Comment: Getting `fatal: unable to access 'https://user:password@github.com/user/repo.git/': gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized`

Comment: While it works, copying github passwords into your source code isn't very secure. The current solution is to add credentials to the ssh link and then deploy, as suggested below by Allam Matsubara.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem with the solution presented [here](http://answers.atlassian.com/questions/160575/conq-repository-access-deniedhttp://). Simply do this:

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`